# gwt-dev-mac.jar is missing?

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to use IntelliJ IDEA for GWT development on Mac OS X, and checked out a project from subversion a coworker created on Windows. The Project file came with paths to GWT ("C:..."), which obviously don't work for me.

When I change the GWT facet path in the Module Settings dialog it complains that the directory i've chosen isn't a valid GWT SDK folder because it's missing gwt-dev-mac.jar

But I can't find such a file anywhere on my machine.

When I rename "gwt-dev.jar" to "gwt-dev-mac.jar" and try to run the project, I get the error: "Unknown argument: -style" when it tries to run GWTShell.

I read this link, but I'm not sure what to do about it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-26017

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dumb... when I updated IntelliJ I dragged the new application into my applications folder and assumed it would replace the old one.

It appeared with the typical greyed-out look because I hadn't started it yet... so I was still using IntelliJ 8.something. and not noticing.

Problem solved with version 9 with the addition of the "Fix" and "Create Artifact" features that appear where the error used to.