# Where do I find gwt-dev-windows.jar ? It does not look like it was included in the GWT SDK for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I'm on Step 5 of doing my first [GWTTestCase](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideTesting.html#DevGuideJUnitIntegration).  I can't find the required "gwt-dev-windows.jar".  I'm on Eclipse 3.5 and GWT SDK

```
Run your test case. Use the class junit.textui.TestRunner as your main class and pass 
the full name of your test class as the command line argument, e.g. com.example.foo.client.FooTest. When running the test case, make sure your classpath includes:
Your project's src directory
Your project's bin directory
The gwt-user.jar library
One of gwt-dev-windows.jar, gwt-dev-linux.jar, or gwt-dev-mac.jar depending on your platform
The junit.jar library
```

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251523/gwt-dev-mac-jar-is-missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like they might have stopped including it, maybe because it is not necessary anymore I have not been following.

However if you do need it you would be able to take it from the standalone GWT SDK download.
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/download.html

Select Download SDK and it will download the SDK for your OS/platform. Inside the zip the jar will be there.

I know in my Eclipse 3.5 GWT SDK for GWT 1.6.4 I had the dev-windows jar in:

> \eclipse\plugins\com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.win32_1.6.4.v200904062334\gwt-windows-1.6.4